# Overlapping a div within another div

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have an HTML table realized as a bunch of divs (for making a scrollable table).

In one of the cells (a div), I want to show a popup which overlaps other cells.

Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/pFx6m/

My markup:

```
<div class="dataRow">
    <div class="firstCell">lalala</div>
    <div class="secondCell">lululu</div>
    <div class="thirdCell">
        <div id="someBigContent"></div>  
        <div class="clearRight"></div></div>
    </div>

<div class="dataRow">
    <div class="firstCell">lalala</div>
    <div class="secondCell">lululu</div>
    <div class="thirdCell">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="dataRow">
    <div class="firstCell">lalala</div>
    <div class="secondCell">lululu</div>
    <div class="thirdCell">lilili</div>
</div>​
```

My CSS:

```
.dataRow {
    height: 30px;    
    width:300px;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.dataRow > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.firstCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.secondCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

.thirdCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.clearRight {
    clear: right;
}

#someBigContent {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -50px;
    float:right;

    z-index: 999;
}
​
```

Now I'm doing something wrong, because it doesn't overlap the cells left of the `someBigContent` (cells one and two) and it makes some rows bigger than they're supposed to be.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFx6m/) for an overview of the situation.

How can I just make the cells overlap (and maybe the content that is under there — not just the table)?

Comment: Since you are using `<div>`s to create a table, please add W3C ARIA roles in to make it *act* like a `<table>` still: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Accessibility/TableHeaders#Example_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that CSS the block `#someBigContent` will not affect the rows or cells sizes:

```
.dataRow {
    height: 30px;    
    width:300px;
    max-height: 30px;
}

.dataRow > div {
    display: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.firstCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.secondCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

.thirdCell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.clearRight {
    clear: right;
}

#someBigContent {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;        
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Now you can adjust the position of this block relative to parent cell.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange to see an table made out of div's...

but try in CSS to add

```
max-width: 100px !important;
```

For the div/table thing that breaks out ?

Comment: thanks, but it results in http://jsfiddle.net/pFx6m/5/ - it does not overlap the other rows/cells